# How can I concatenate 2 pairs of columns so that the resulting 2 columns have alternating rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate columns 1 and 2 with columns 3 and 4 and have them alternate rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], '2': [5, 10, 15, 15],
             '3': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'], '4': [3, 1, 5, 9]})
```

```
    1   2   3  4
0  A1   5  B1  3
1  A2  10  B2  1
2  A3  15  B3  5
3  A4  15  B4  9
```

This is my expected result

```
A1  5  
B1  3
A2  10  
B2  1
A3  15  
B3  5
A4  15  
B4  9
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Quang Hoang your comment was helpful. The below code ended up accomplishing what I needed.

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 2))
```

```
    0   1
0  A1   5
1  B1   3
2  A2  10
3  B2   1
4  A3  15
5  B3   5
6  A4  15
7  B4   9
```